# Color of the Fur coat of Polar bears

Tags: zoology

Recently I was playing a quiz and a question was asked about the color of the fur coat of a polar bear. To my surprise the answer was black. I thought it was yellowish white or creamy. Why so ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fur coats of polar bears are in fact clear tubes - not white fur as is often believed. It is their *skin* that is black, to absorb the most warmth from the sun (and the clear tubes allow the majority of the light to pass through to the skin).

I recently watched the BBC's Frozen Planet TV series (with David Attenborough), where I heard the above answer. If you haven't already, I recommend watching it.

Comment: Also the tubular hairs, like a hollofil padding, are better insulators than solid hairs so they keep more heat in the bear.